# Selenium: how to find the number of childNodes of a div

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have been banging my head on this for the better part of a day; I need to count the number of childNodes in a parent div. It basically is acting like a list and each childNode is a row I want to count. The html looks like:

```
div<@class="list "> 
   div<@id="list-item-01">
   div<@id="list-item-02">
   div<@id="list-item-03">
   div<@id="list-item-04">
   div<@id="list-item-05">
   ...
</div>
```

My primary approach has been to use the `getEval()` function in Selenium using some javascript.

examples that have failed:

```
String locator = "xpath=//div[contains(@class,'list')]";
String jscript = "var element = this.browserbot.findElement('"+locator+"');";
       jscript += "element.childNodes.length;";

String locator = "xpath=//div[@class='list']";
String jscript = "var element = this.browserbot.findElement('"+locator+"');";
       jscript += "element.childNodes.length;";
```

Now I know the element is there and my xpath is correct because I have tried using `.isElementPresent` and that returns true. So something is funky with Selenium and divs.

I also poked around with `document.evaluate()` as my javascript command but that proved equally fruitless.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `getXPathCount`? Something like

```
getXPathCount("//div[contains(@class, 'list ')]/div[contains(@class, 'list-item-')]")
```

should do the trick.

[.Net documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.ISelenium.GetXpathCount.html)

[Java documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getXpathCount%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: since he wants the count of items within a div you may want to amend your xpath to take that into account

Answer (score 0):

So these divs are created  dynamically .
So  when you create this , you will be using a variable for iteration like $i , $i++.

after printing divs add that value of $i to a hidden field.

if there are 3 divs , $i=3 , putvalue of hidden=3

just get the value of that field using javascript.

Or

Try  these

http://api.jquery.com/parent/
http://api.jquery.com/children/